# Telegram bot C#. Oтправка mp3 файла

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram, sendmessage

Подскажите пожалуйста как отправить аудио запись через телеграмм-бот.
Написал бота, сделал Inline-клавиатуру (менюшку), обработал нажатие каждой кнопки через switch - case. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на каждую inline-кнопку, бот оправлял локальную аудио запись. Все аудио находятся в папке проекта. Буду признателен, если подскажете с самим кодом, а то я пока еще новичок в C# и первый раз пробую делать бота.

Comment: Какую библиотеку используете для создания telegram-бота, [Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot)? Приложите, пожалуйста, свой пример кода, который нужно доработать.    Но сначала прочитайте общую теорию по отправке файлов через Telegram API [Sending files](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files) и пример отправки файлов через библиотеку Telegram.Bot [Uploading files](https://telegrambots.github.io/book/3/files/upload.html).

Comment: Да, пользуюсь библиотекой Telegram.Bot. Указанные источники изучал, пытался применить, но постоянно возникали ошибки компиляции (навыков у меня маловато пока что...)

Comment: ```private static async void BotOnCallbackQueryReceived(object sender, CallbackQueryEventArgs e)
               {
                var id = e.CallbackQuery.From.Id;
                var buttonText = e.CallbackQuery.Data;
                
                switch (e.CallbackQuery.Data)
                {
                    case "Audio_1":```
                 // Здесь мне собственно и нужна помощь с методом отправки аудио файла. 
                    ```break;
                }```

Comment: Сначала я создал обычную клавиатуру, при нажатии кнопки у меня создается inline-меню c треками. И мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии inline-кнопки Audio_1, отправлялся mp3 файл

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите за основу пример для библиотеки Telegram.Bot: [Handlers.cs](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Examples/blob/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.Polling/Handlers.cs).

В методе [SendInlineKeyboard](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Examples/blob/76c554ae86c9d503db6ff18a96f7f34000220913/Telegram.Bot.Examples.Polling/Handlers.cs#L72) код, который у вас уже реализован. В комментарии к этому методу написано, что обработать ответ можно в [BotOnCallbackQueryReceived](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Examples/blob/76c554ae86c9d503db6ff18a96f7f34000220913/Telegram.Bot.Examples.Polling/Handlers.cs#L167).

> You can process responses in BotOnCallbackQueryReceived handler

Вам нужно написать метод по аналогии с примером:

```
private static async Task BotOnCallbackQueryReceived(ITelegramBotClient botClient, CallbackQuery callbackQuery)
{
    await botClient.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(
        callbackQueryId: callbackQuery.Id,
        text: $"Received {callbackQuery.Data}");

    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
        chatId: callbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id,
        text: $"Received {callbackQuery.Data}");
}
```

Только вместо вызова метода SendTextMessageAsync надо создать и вызвать метод по примеру метода [SendFile](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Examples/blob/76c554ae86c9d503db6ff18a96f7f34000220913/Telegram.Bot.Examples.Polling/Handlers.cs#L125). Выбор файла в зависимости от номера трека можно реализовать здесь в зависимости от содержания callbackQuery.Data.

```
static async Task<Message> SendFile(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Message message)
{
    await botClient.SendChatActionAsync(message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.UploadPhoto);

    const string filePath = @"Files/tux.png";
    using FileStream fileStream = new(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    var fileName = filePath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();

    return await botClient.SendPhotoAsync(chatId: message.Chat.Id,
                                          photo: new InputOnlineFile(fileStream, fileName),
                                          caption: "Nice Picture");
}
```

И для того, чтобы все это заработало, необходимо добавить обработчик по аналогии с [HandleUpdateAsync](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Examples/blob/76c554ae86c9d503db6ff18a96f7f34000220913/Telegram.Bot.Examples.Polling/Handlers.cs#L24), который указать при старте бота.
Пример привязки метода обновления и старта бота тут [Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling#usage).

Итоговый алгоритм:

1. При старте бота передать метод, который отслеживает обновления.
2. В методе обновления вызывать метод BotOnCallbackQueryReceived, если тип update.Type == UpdateType.CallbackQuery.
3. В методе BotOnCallbackQueryReceived обработать callbackQuery и в зависимости от данных в нем вызвать отправку нужного файла.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться